# Javascript и второй монитор

Tags: html, javascript

Браузер семейства Google. Страничка html локальная (можно с ней делать что угодно, писать в неё что угодно).
Как по клику на ссылку открыть новое окно (желательно без адресной строки и пр.) на втором мониторе?
Доп.вопрос: как посредство js узнать разрешение этого второго монитора?

Comment: Узнать разрешение монитора можно так http://jsfiddle.net/T2W3W/4/ (для примеры вызывается при клике на кнопку)

Comment: Это то я знаю... Спасибо.
Мне нужно переключиться на второй монитор.
Перемещаю окно во второй монитор - запускаю скрипт - всё равно разрешение первого монитора показывает...

Comment: @zgtv насколько я понял, погуглив, ни один из современных браузеров не озаботился определением разрешения текущего монитора (а может и вовсе второго).

Comment: Для решения аналогичной задачи я как то раз писал расширение к браузеру.

Comment: @Nofate а как там с мультиплатформенностью было ?

Comment: @eicto, проект был по жестким требованиям на IE9 под Windows 7. Какая уж там мультиплатформенность )

Answer (score 1):

> Страничка html локальная (можно с ней делать что угодно, писать в неё что угодно)

может стоит посмотреть в сторону hta или вовсе обойтись без html?

---

Возможно будет полезным http://jsfiddle.net/0fted8gp/

Источник: [Dual Monitors and window.open()](http://archive.cpradio.org/code/javascript/dual-monitors-and-windowopen/)

Если коротко: window.screenLeft на вторичном левом мониторе будет отрицательным :)

```js
// Find Left Boundry of current Window
function FindLeftWindowBoundry()
{
 // In Internet Explorer window.screenLeft is the window's left boundry
 if (window.screenLeft)
 {
  return window.screenLeft;
 }
 
 // In Firefox window.screenX is the window's left boundry
 if (window.screenX)
  return window.screenX;
  
 return 0;
}

window.leftWindowBoundry = FindLeftWindowBoundry;

// Find Left Boundry of the Screen/Monitor
function FindLeftScreenBoundry()
{
 // Check if the window is off the primary monitor in a positive axis
 // X,Y                  X,Y                    S = Screen, W = Window
 // 0,0  ----------   1280,0  ----------
 //     |          |         |  ---     |
 //     |          |         | | W |    |
 //     |        S |         |  ---   S |
 //      ----------           ----------
 if (window.leftWindowBoundry() > window.screen.width)
 {
  return window.leftWindowBoundry() - (window.leftWindowBoundry() - window.screen.width);
 }
 
 // Check if the window is off the primary monitor in a negative axis
 // X,Y                  X,Y                    S = Screen, W = Window
 // 0,0  ----------  -1280,0  ----------
 //     |          |         |  ---     |
 //     |          |         | | W |    |
 //     |        S |         |  ---   S |
 //      ----------           ----------
 // This only works in Firefox at the moment due to a bug in Internet Explorer opening new windows into a negative axis
 // However, you can move opened windows into a negative axis as a workaround
 if (window.leftWindowBoundry() < 0 && window.leftWindowBoundry() > (window.screen.width * -1))
 {
  return (window.screen.width * -1);
 }
 
 // If neither of the above, the monitor is on the primary monitor whose's screen X should be 0
 return 0;
}

window.leftScreenBoundry = FindLeftScreenBoundry;

window.open('http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/279949/javascript-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80', 'windowName', 'resizable=1, scrollbars=1, fullscreen=1, height=200, width=650, screenX=' + window.leftScreenBoundry() + ' , left=' + window.leftScreenBoundry() + ', toolbar=0, menubar=0, status=1');
```